# My eclipse takes a lot of memory space from time to time

Tags: python, eclipse

Whenever, I use eclipse it starts to delay my input when I type. I opened task manager to check how much memory was being used(In the picture below), it seemed to be quite high. How do I reduce the memory taken? (I have a 16 BG RAM)

[According to task manager, eclipse currently occupies 9435.6 MB and the Python that is being used is repeated 9 teams when you expand the task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni3WU.png)

I tried to close the program and restart it, but unfortunately the same problem kept on occurring.

```
class _Deque_Node:

def __init__(self, value, _prev, _next):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Initializes a deque node.
    Use: node = _Deque_Node(value, _prev, _next)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Parameters:
        value - value value for node (?)
        _prev - another deque node (_Deque_Node)
        _next - another deque node (_Deque_Node)
    Returns:
        a new _Deque_Node object (_Deque_Node)

    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    self._value = deepcopy(value)
    self._prev = _prev
    self._next = _next
```

class Deque:

```
def __init__(self):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Initializes an empty deque.
    Use: d = deque()
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Returns:
        a new Deque object (Deque)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    self._front = None
    self._rear = None
    self._count = 0

def is_empty(self):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Determines if the deque is empty.
    Use: b = deque.is_empty()
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Returns:
        True if the deque is empty, False otherwise.
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    return 

def __len__(self):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Returns the size of the deque.
    Use: n = len(deque)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Returns:
        the number of values in the deque (int)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """ 
    return t

def __eq__(self, target):
    """
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    Determines whether two Deques are equal.
    Values in self and target are compared and if all values are equal
    and in the same order, returns True, otherwise returns False.
    Use: equals = source == target
    ---------------
    Parameters:
        target - a deque (Deque)
    Returns:
        equals - True if source contains the same values
            as target in the same order, otherwise False. (boolean)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    
    return

def insert_front(self, value):
           
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Inserts a copy of value into the front of the deque.
    Use: deque.insert_front(value)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Parameters:
        value - a data element (?)
    Returns:
        None
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """

    return

def insert_rear(self, value):
    
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Inserts a copy of value into the rear of the deque.
    Use: deque.insert_rear(value)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Parameters:
        value - a data element (?)
    Returns:
        None
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """

    return

def remove_front(self):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Removes and returns value from the front of the deque.
    Use: v = deque.remove_front()
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Returns:
        value - the value at the front of deque (?)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
    
        
    return value

def remove_rear(self):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Removes and returns value from the rear of the deque.
    Use: v = deque.remove_rear()
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Returns:
        value - the value at the rear of deque (?)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """
      
    return value

def peek_front(self):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Peeks at the front of deque.
    Use: v = deque.peek_front()
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Returns:
        value - a copy of the value at the front of deque (?)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """

    return deepcopy(value)

def peek_rear(self):
    
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Peeks at the rear of deque.
    Use: v = deque.peek_rear()
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Returns:
        value - a copy of the value at the rear of deque (?)
    -------------------------------------------------------

    return deepcopy(value)

def _swap(self, l, r):
    """
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Swaps two nodes within a deque. l has taken the place of r, 
    r has taken the place of l and _front and _rear are updated 
    as appropriate. Data is not moved.
    Use: self._swap(self, l, r):
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Parameters:
        l - a pointer to a deque node (_Deque_Node)
        r - a pointer to a deque node (_Deque_Node)
    Returns:
        None
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """

        

    return

def __iter__(self):
    """
    USE FOR TESTING ONLY
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Generates a Python iterator. Iterates through the deque
    from front to rear.
    Use: for v in d:
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Returns:
        yields
        value - the next value in the deque (?)
    -------------------------------------------------------
    """

    current = self._front

    while current is not None:
        yield current._value
        current = current._next
```

Comment: Eclipse doesn't use Python, so are you using a plug-in that would be starting python processes?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @nitind I am using a plugin that would be using a python process as I use eclipse for coding in python

Comment: @TobokSitanggang Sure! I have added the code I am working with.